# reading out Plist issue

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, plist

Why is the naam output (NULL)? (sorry In know this is basic stuff, but I am new with plists)

This is the plist: 
[image]

Here's the method:

```
- (id) init {

self = [super init];
if (self) {
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *plistPath;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSLog(@"path: %@",plistPath);
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

    NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                          propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                          mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                          format:&format
                                          errorDescription:&errorDesc];
      NSLog(@"temp: %@",temp);
    if (!temp) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    }
    self.personName = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"NAAM:%@",[temp objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    self.phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Phones"]];


}
return self;}
```

[image: the output]

Answer (score 1):

Because temp is a dictionary that contains only one key: @"Root". You are looking for an object in the inner dictionary: `[[temp objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"Name"]`

Comment: Thank you; that works. How can I (only) read Item 1 in Phones?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
NSLog(@"NAAM: %@", [temp valueForKeyPath:@"Root.Name"]);
```

To tread first phone from `Phones` do this:

```
NSDictionary *root = [temp valueForKey:@"Root"];
[[root valueForKey:@"Phones"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I (only) read Item 1 in Phones after extracting ROOT?

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting ROOT first.

```
NSDictionary* root=[temp objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSLog(@"NAAM:%@",[root objectForKey:@"Name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I (only) read Item 1 in Phones after extracting ROOT?

Comment: something like this: `NSArray* phones=[root objectForKey:@"Phones"]; NSString* phone1=[phones objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 0):

my "Words.plist"

```
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>sunday</string>
        <string>monday</string>
        <integer>44</integer>
    </array>
</dict>


NSString *StringsFromPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *itemPositionPlistLocation = [StringsFromPList stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Words.plist"];
 _myDictionary= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
NSArray * items = [_myDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSLog(@"%@", items);
```

Hope it helps a bit :)